# How do I move files with a certain word in their name, but only those files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I am trying to write a program that will sort my files into folders based on the names of the files using Python. However, I am unsure on how to do this.

This is what I know how to do already, which moves a file, but only one.

```
import shutil

original = r'C:\Users\******\Documents\stacktest\cat1.txt'
new = r'C:\Users\******\Documents\stacktest\cat\cat1.txt'

shutil.move(original, new)
```

This moves the cat1.txt file into the cat folder.

Sorry if this post isn't clear. I'll try to clarify if needed. If anyone can help me figure this out, then thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which files you want to move, say, you have some criteria upfront. If you have the explicit list of files, just let `filenames=<list of names>` and skip reading all the files and filtering them.

```
import os
import shutil

folder_from = r'C:\Users\******\Documents\stacktest'
folder_two = r'C:\Users\******\Documents\stacktest\cat'

# read all files in the folder
# note that os.listdir returns all files and directories in the folder
filenames = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_from) if os.isfile(os.join(folder_from, f))]

# filter filenames by the criteria you have in mind
filenames = list(map(<function that filters>, filenames))

# move the files
for f in filenames:
    shutil.move(os.path.join(folder_from, f), os.path.join(folder_to, f))
```